# New-SMBShare not working when path is a variable

Tags: powershell

Following is working:

```
$ New-SMBShare  -name "xyz$" -Path "C:\TEMP\smbshare4" -FullAccess "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users"
```

But not this one where I pass `-path` as a variable `$dirPath="C:\TEMP\\smbshare4"`

```
$ New-SMBShare  -name "xyz$" -Path  $dirPath  -FullAccess "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users"

New-SMBShare : The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-SMBShare  -name "xyz$" -Path  $dirPath  -FullAccess "NT AUTHORITY\Authentica ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified (MSFT_SMBShare:ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/SMB/MSFT_SMBShare) [New-SmbShare], CimException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 123,New-SmbShare
```

Comment: Is that a typo, or do you have an extra backslash in `$dirPath="C:\TEMP\\smbshare4"`?

Comment: Yes, that was it, thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

Double backward slashes "\" was the problem.

$dirPath="C:\TEMP\smbshare4" worked.